# Simulation Audio Signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, microphone

I have a problem with the capturing audio signals which are impinging to a microphone array using matlab. I have two audio files : one is a signal of interest and other is the noise. I want to simulate the way the microphones received that two signals.

Given the locations of the two sound sources in Cartesian system as well as the Azimuth and Elevation angles of the two signals. (The azimuth will be used as the direction of arrival angle to the microphone array).

How can I simulate this kind of test in Matlab ?

Comment: MATLAB is a powerful computational tool, but it'll do what you tell it to do, and nothing more. You need to come up with an algorithm first, and then think about MATLAB and implementation. Do you have the exact computations planned out?

Comment: We can't do your work for you, and this is not a simple problem. If there is a specific problem you are having, maybe you should post about that.